# What's the most popular programming language for creating websites?

Tags: web-development

I want to know the details of websites developed using the different languages like .Net, Java, PHP, Python. Which programming language is mostly used?

Comment: This has been converted to community wiki because there is no definitive answer and any answer could be argumentative.  This is not really on topic for our website but I will leave it open because there are a number of good answers already.

Answer (score 5):

TIOBE publish a [monthly league table](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html) of the most popular programming languages. The four you mention are currently ranked in the following order:

1. Java
2. C#
3. PHP
4. Python

Note that the TIOBE tables are based on an algorithm that tries to determine the number of lines of code written in each language every month using results from the major search engines, so they're not necessarily an indication of the number of *websites* using those programming languages, but it probably gives a fair indication.

What it doesn't take into account is the number of websites deployed using off-the-shelf blogging packages and CMS such as WordPress etc. If it were possible to count the number of active websites using each programming language, I suspect PHP would come slightly higher than the popularity table suggests.

Netcraft also surveys millions of sites every month to determine what server platform they use. The latest results available to date ([July 2011](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2011/07/08/july-2011-web-server-survey.html)) won't give you a precise indication of the underlying programming language (only the web server), but it serves as a useful reference point:

[image: popular web servers across all domains, as surveyed by netcraft]

Data on programming language use among active websites is very hard to come by, largely because it's not always obvious from generated code and server responses which language is being used. As such, it's hard to tell what language a site's written in without asking.

Comment: Can you please provide any other link. Here we want to find out whether most sites hosted by Java technologies or Microsoft technologies.

Comment: @Krishna Answer updated with more information regarding web servers. You're unlikely to find any meaningful data on active sites and programming languages, though. (I'm not sure how useful it would be if you did have it, to be honest; it's best to evaluate technologies based on your own needs, not on how many other people use X over Y.)

Comment: This information is misleading, Java, C# and Python are also used in desktop development, and TIOBE counts these uses too.

Comment: @M28 I mention that it's only a rough indication in my answer.

Comment: @Nick I don't think it's anywhere near a "rough indication". Very few websites use Java as a back-end. C# and PHP show almost the same usage, and 99% of PHP is on websites whereas for C# it could easily be 50%.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat If you discount the languages that we all know aren't readily used for website development, the TIOBE table hints at a hierarchy that doesn't seem far from what you'd expect. (e.g. PHP at the top, followed by Python and Ruby.) I agree with you that it's not an ideal data point but maintain that it's still useful, especially when you consider that there are few if any large-scale reports on programming languages used on active websites. (If you do know of one, though, please share it!)

Comment: To some degree Windows vs Linux is not important because you can serve PHP, C#, and numerous other languages from both Windows and Linux.  Also, the question doesn't ask that and shouldn't as that would be a separate question.

Answer (score 5):

[PHP](http://www.php.net) is the [most used by far](http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/programming_language/all). The fact the entire stack is free helps but it gained its popularity because of the ease of integration. It is extremely easy combine static HTML with PHP or even add features to a static side.

There is also a huge volume of general-purpose platforms written in PHP. Think that every Wordpress-Powered blog or site is a PHP site. There are tons more and plenty of others are hugely popular.

It turns out that the most popular is different from the most used depending how you count. For very large and complex sites, people tend to prefer something more structured such as Python, Java and C++. Often, the largest sites will use a combination of languages.

For historical reasons, certain languages get adopted at different rates depending on the domain. For example, after PHP, content sites often use Python. Banking and service sites are more likely to use Java. C++ and assembly is often used to boost performance in key areas but I have not seen any (there probably are some though) written entirely using these.

Comment: **citation needed**

Comment: For the top server-side language being PHP: http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/programming_language/all

Comment: I added this link to the actual question where it should be, but I do not have enough rep so it is waiting on approval.

Comment: Just to remember: Typo3 also is PHP-based.

Comment: Their methodology is rather flawed. It looks like they determine the language used by looking at file extensions in the URL … and the top three languages are the ones I'd have said were the most likely to have file extensions in the URL.

Answer (score -1):

PHP is mostly used in web development and Java & asp.net are also popular.

For larger websites combination of languages like Java, Python, PHP are used (like for Facebook).